# Bing maps url parameters for street view at a lat long

Tags: latitude-longitude, bing-maps

I am trying to create a url to use to open a Bing street side view based on lat long positions but it keeps taking me to the wrong location.  Here is the lat long for the location I am looking for street view at.

[image]

Here the url that I am creating based on the click point in my arcgis map
https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?-116.393797,43.590106&lvl=17.79637&dir=265.4691&pi=-0.297&style=x&mo=z.0&ftst=0&ftics=False&v=2&sV=1

Here's where it takes me.

[image]

Here the lat long of the street side where bing maps opens the view of.

[image]

I am confused.  I can't find the parameters needed for displaying streetside at based on lat long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, documentation on how to create URL's for bing.com can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx

Currently information on showing a streetview location is not documented. However, looking at the URL's from the website it is fairly easy to figure this out.

Your current URL has one big issue, the coordinates are reversed and comma separated rather than "~" separated and they aren't passed in a URL parameter. Here is a modified version of the URL: https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?cp=43.590119~-116.393826&lvl=17&dir=113.8911&pi=-0.284&style=x&v=2&sV=1

That said, the Bing Maps website is a consumer site for consumer use and really shouldn't be used for commercial purposes. The Bing Maps V8 map control has streetside in it and can be integrated with your application. http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#setViewToStreetside+JS

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much Ricky.  I was trying to watch the url change in the browser when clicking to street view but I didn't see it.  I am only using this for a personal arcgis streetside addin in my maps.